# Using Django SimpleHistory and TabularInline together

Tags: django, django-admin, django-simple-history

I want to display the **ModelA** as a TabularInline of **ModelB** and at the same time want to maintain the history of changes to **ModelA** using the Django simple history module.

Is there a way to do this? Went through the official documentation of both TabularInline and Django simpleHistory but couldn't get much out of it.

Model A

```
class ModelAInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ModelA

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Model B

```
class ModelBAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name",)
    search_fields = ("name",)
    readonly_fields = ("last_changed",)
    inlines = (ModelAInline,)
```

Answer (score 1):

How you display in the admin doesn't factor in to whether or not the history of changes is maintained. You can register `ModelA` as another admin view that inherits from `SimpleHistoryAdmin` so that you can view history on it, but as long as `ModelA` is registered with django-simple-history, the history of the model will be tracked.